# Multi Images for One Unit in Drupal

Tags: image, drupal, module

I'm developing Drupal ecommerce site, using Drupal Room Module.
I need to show some images for one unit.
In other word, each unit has several images for description.

I've seen Product has this feature, but I can't find it in Drupal Rooms Module.
I have no idea where I can do this stuff, in Bookable Units or Bookable Unit Description?

There are no options for that in both.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i do get you right.

Go to

```
/admin/structure/types/manage/unit_description/fields
```

and add a fieldtype that can hold images.

All the best